# Android SyncAdapter minimum time interval

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I've added a SyncAdapter to my application which syncs data from the server to the sqlite database in Android. I'm using a stub `ContentProvider`. I've enabled `setSyncAutomatically` and `addPeriodicSync` for my syncAdapter. I've set the periodic sync interval to 15 minutes.

The **problem** is that although most of the times its works perfectly but sometimes my application starts doing repeated syncs, like 2-3 sync together one after the another.

I figured that this might be due to using `setSyncAutomatically` but if I remove this then I've to manually go to settings and enable my application's auto sync.

My code -

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, Constant.AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, Constant.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(newAccount, Constant.AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), Constant.SYNC_FREQUENCY);
```

Is there a way I can set a minimum interval to my syncAdapter so that it doesn't execute again until this time interval?

Comment: What's the content of the extras `Bundle` for these syncs (the planned ones and the additional ones)?

Comment: Nothing. I just pass a new Bundle().

Comment: I meant the Bundle that your sync adapter actually receives. It may tell why the sync was triggered in the first place.

Comment: sorry I don't follow. Which bundle should I check? I only pass the bundle mentioned in the code above.

Comment: the [onPerformSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html#onPerformSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentProviderClient,%20android.content.SyncResult%29) method of your sync adapter gets an extras Bundle (the 2nd parameter) that contains the values that you pass in your Bundle plus some keys added by the sync manager. These keys may tell why the sync has been triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum sync interval, but you could track that yourself. Just store the last sync time and exit your sync adapter without syncing if the minimum interval has not passed yet.

However, the proper solution would be to find out why those additional syncs are triggered in the first place.

Enabling automatic sync using [`setSyncAutomatically()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setSyncAutomatically%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) means that Android should trigger a sync whenever the content provider posts a change notification using [`ContentResolver.notifyChange(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29) with the `syncToNetwork` parameter set to `true`. You should make sure that you never set this parameter to `true` for changes made by your sync adapter.

Comment: Nope I never set it to true. I don't use the content provider anywhere.

Comment: Do you ever trigger a sync using [requestSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) in your code?